# Java Face Detection with OpenImaj

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to implement a fuction that checks whether a png image contains a human face. I am trying to use OpenImaj and noticed that it has 4 detectors (Identity, Haar etc)

Appreciate if anyone can share a relevant  code snippet

Comment: Your question is off-topic on Stackoverflow but you could try asking on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help

Comment: I wonder how come it is off topic? Isn&#39;t SOF is all about code solutions to common problems like I have? there are many posts here on face detection with OpenCV, why can not I ask on different implementation ?

Comment: "Questions asking us to _recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource_ are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." - [help/on-topic]

Comment: I changed the question accordingly, hope this format is more suitable

Comment: I agree with your assertion that a lot of attention is on opencv - but a simple search gave you that. Another one which is probably burried in the search is http://www.richardnichols.net/2011/01/java-facial-recognition-haar-cascade-with-jjil-guide/. I have used it in movies and is usually 70% accurate, maybe 50% if the shading is bad, But for persons looking straight is ok. I don't think this other one is any better, You have to use a lot of fixes and tricks  to achieve over 90% - in the general situation - not just a guy talking to his web camera

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import org.openimaj.image.DisplayUtilities;
import org.openimaj.image.FImage;
import org.openimaj.image.ImageUtilities;
import org.openimaj.image.MBFImage;
import org.openimaj.image.colour.RGBColour;
import org.openimaj.image.colour.Transforms;
import org.openimaj.image.processing.face.detection.DetectedFace;
import org.openimaj.image.processing.face.detection.FaceDetector;
import org.openimaj.image.processing.face.detection.HaarCascadeDetector;
import org.openimaj.math.geometry.shape.Rectangle;


public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception, IOException {


        final MBFImage image = ImageUtilities.readMBF(new File("d:\\java\\face\\bin.jpeg"));

        FaceDetector<DetectedFace, FImage> fd = new HaarCascadeDetector(200);
        List<DetectedFace> faces = fd.detectFaces(Transforms.calculateIntensity(image));
        System.out.println("# Found faces, one per line.");
        System.out.println("# <x>, <y>, <width>, <height>");

        for (Iterator<DetectedFace> iterator = faces.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            DetectedFace face = iterator.next();
            Rectangle bounds = face.getBounds();

            image.drawShape(face.getBounds(), RGBColour.RED);

            // System.out.println(bounds.x + ";" + bounds.y + ";" + bounds.width + ";" +
            // bounds.height);

        }

        DisplayUtilities.display(image);

    }
}
```